# How to set font to Verdana throughout the entire document in Overleaf?

Tags: fonts

The document is now in Times New Roman. How do I switch to Verdana? (overleaf does not recognise `\RequirePackage{verdana}`.

```
%% Fonts
\if@times\RequirePackage{times}\fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Overleaf offers a quick reference for setting different fonts for a document, or using them in-line

1. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces
2. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles

Comment: I've tried uploading a ttf file and adding '\usepackage{fontspec}' so my document.
However, I receive an error message:

I.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
 /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty, line 45
Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or

Comment: In the case that you need the XeTeX (because apparently LaTeX doesn't do extra fonts out the box), they offer this guide: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX. In your document, click the [Menu] in the upper left, and then change "Compiler" to XeTeX. Does that get it done?

Comment: @Tess as the error mentions fontspec does not support pdflatex, you'll need another engine.

Comment: It works! However, not the entire text is in Verdana. I've used

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\setverdanafont[BoldFont=Fonts/Verdana Bold.ttf, ItalicFont=Fonts/Verdana Italic.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf,]{Fonts/Verdana.ttf}

But the error im getting is: 'Undefined Control Sequence'

l.11 \setverdanafont
                    [BoldFont=Fonts/Verdana Bold.ttf, Italic...
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox').

Comment: The formatting of the command you've added and the error message is a little difficult to understand in the comment here. Could you edit your original question and add the new steps you've taken? I can try and help from there :)